Previous dynamic inputs do not disappear when replaced by new ones
I made a Shiny app where the user can choose from three series of words. When the user chooses series 1, the user can choose from 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd'. When the user chooses series 2, the user can choose from 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' and 'i', etc. The code is as follows:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(selectInput('replyWord', 'Word:', choices = 1:3, selected = "", selectize=FALSE, size=3), uiOutput("showWord"))

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  global <- reactiveValues(words=c())

  shinyInputId <- function(prefix, id) 
  {
    paste(prefix, id, sep = "_")
  }

  output$showWord <- renderUI(
  {
    req(input$replyWord, global$words)

    lapply(seq(length(global$words)), function(i) 
      uiOutput(shinyInputId("button", i))
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$replyWord, 
  {
    req(input$replyWord)

    if (input$replyWord==1) global$words <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
    if (input$replyWord==2) global$words <- c("e", "f", "g", "h", "i")
    if (input$replyWord==3) global$words <- c("j", "k", "l")

    lapply(seq(length(global$words)), function(i) 
    {
      Name <- global$words[i]
      gen.input <- shinyInputId("button", i)

      output[[gen.input]] <- renderUI(
      {
        actionButton(inputId = gen.input, label = Name)
      })
    
      observeEvent(input[[gen.input]], 
      {
        print(paste("You clicked", Name))
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

This code was inspired by the code at https://gist.github.com/strboul/310dc3d546437f40429e7a837f1de07c.
In the console a message appears each time a word has been chosen, and in the message it is mentioned which word has been chosen.
However, after having chosen a word from series 1 and switching to series 2, the chosen words from series 1 are still kept, and when choosing a word from series 2, say the second word 'f', the second word of series 1 'b' is mentioned as well in the console, which is not what I want.
Somehow it looks if I need to erase explicitely the choices of a series when switching to another series, but I do not know how. Any ideas?

Nesting observers and output$var inside observers is not a good idea.  Also, you are creating actionButton each time user selects replyWord.  Please avoid that as in your example link.

My case is more complicated than the one in the example link, since there are three series, which may also differ in length (as it is now, I changed this). I understand your comments but are not sure how to implement this.

Try to define unique IDs.  In the current set-up you are using button_1 as ID to represent "a" in series 1, "e" in series 2 and "j" in series 3.  You can make them unique by adding input$replyWord to the ID.  Try this
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(selectInput('replyWord', 'Word:', choices = 1:3, selected = "", selectize=FALSE, size=3), uiOutput("showWord"))

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  global <- reactiveValues(words=c())
  
  shinyInputId <- function(word,prefix, id) 
  {
    paste(word, prefix, id, sep = "_")
  }
  
  output$showWord <- renderUI(
    {
      req(input$replyWord, global$words)
      
      lapply(seq(length(global$words)), function(i) 
        uiOutput(shinyInputId(input$replyWord,"button", i))
      )
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$replyWord, 
               {
                 req(input$replyWord)
                 
                 if (input$replyWord==1) global$words <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
                 if (input$replyWord==2) global$words <- c("e", "f", "g", "h", "i")
                 if (input$replyWord==3) global$words <- c("j", "k", "l")
                 
                 lapply(seq(length(global$words)), function(i) 
                 {
                   Name <- global$words[i]
                   gen.input <- shinyInputId(input$replyWord,"button", i)
                   
                   output[[gen.input]] <- renderUI(
                     {
                       actionButton(inputId = gen.input, label = Name)
                     })
                   
                   observeEvent(input[[gen.input]], 
                                {
                                  print(paste("You clicked", Name))
                                })
                 })
               })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Making the IDs unique helps. But in case of larger series of words, e.g. 300 per series, the app becomes slow after switching to another series and clicking on a word for the first time. It takes very long before getting the message "You clicked ... ". But then when clicking on a next word, it works fast again. Why takes the first word so much time after switching series?
